# Why does my armature keep moving?

Tags: armature

This is really frustrating. I have tried every possible setting and it will not stop the armature from shifting position in pose mode compared to edit mode. I have not added weights and I have checked all of the axis of every bone and they are the same when I switch from edit to pose mode.
When I attach the model to the armature it leans backwards every time due to the shift in pose mode and the back of the legs also get a slight backward curve.
I have reset alt R and alt G in pose mode each time.
The IK controller bone (bottom bone far left) is clearly causing the armature to leap backwards but none of the settings in the constraints fix it.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to see the bone hierarchy. Can you share the file?

Answer (score 0):

The IK bone will always stick to its controller (the bone that you've called *IK foot.R*) as soon as you'll switch to *Pose* mode. To avoid that, switch to *Edit* mode and stick the head of *IK foot.R* to the tail of the bone that has the IK constraint.